# Client.DownloadFile() C# only write to file when download successful

Tags: c#, file, download

Here is my code to download file using C#

```
Client.DownloadFile("link","file");
```

I want to modify it in such a way so that it will create file, only if download is successful. Currently, if I already have a file in the folder where I am trying to download, the above code deletes current file, if download is not successful.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Comment: You could download to a temporary file and if the download is successful move the temporary file to the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways:

1. Download the file to a temporary name, and when the download is complete you move it to the right place.
2. Use the `DownloadData` method to get the data as a byte array instead, and `File.WriteAllBytes` to save it to the file when you have all the data.

The first option works better for large files, and the second for small files.